# Maven offline - problem with mvn-plugins

Tags: java, maven-2, offline-mode

I'm using maven in my project and I need to run the build in a **non-internet-access** machine.

When I test my project build everything  is working, but when I run the build **in a future moment**, the maven try to **update the mvn-plugins** and this *sh*t* is broking my build.

My config file: ***settings.xml*** from mvn.

```
    <profile>
      <id>blaProfile</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>blaRepo</id>
          <url>file://${bla.3rdParty.home}/maven/.m2/repository</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>blaRepo</id>
          <url>file://${bla.3rdParty.home}/maven/.m2/repository</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>

  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>blaProfile</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
```

And I ran my maven is with the params:

```
mvn -npu -bla.3rdParty.home="$(THE_CORRECT_PATH)" package
```

I saw that maven try to update some mvn-plugins for some time, but the option:

```
-npu,--no-plugin-updates      Suppress upToDate check for any relevant
```

Should work for this updates.

Well waiting some help on that!

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE(1):**
What I'm looking at, is that I could use the setting:

```
<usePluginRegistry>true</usePluginRegistry>
```

Inside my **settings.xml** and with this, I'll have a **plugin-registry.xml** inside ${user.home}/.m2 that I can config and force the maven plugins versions.

But it's not working! **:(**

Comment: Have you've found a reason responsible for this strange behavior?

Comment: Personally I suspect this "issue" can be related to Maven's "Plugin Prefix Resolution", https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html.

Answer (score 10):

Before you go offline run the following:

```
mvn dependency:go-offline
```

That will download all your dependencies and plugins that you need to build your project into ~/.m2/repository.

Once you've run that you can now build your project offline using the '-o' flag:

```
mvn install -o
```

Comment: This is a good point, but my idea is to create a kind of CD/DVD with the procedures to create a war file, with MVN in this example. By that I create a 'file' repository, that contains all dependencies that I need. With your idea I'll have to force the user to put all dependencies into his .m2 dir. This is a option, but I'm running to some other direction.

Comment: It doesn't download plugin dependencies (plugins themselves downloaded but dependent jars are missing) in mvn 3.5.0. Whenever I try to compile with 

    mvn install -o
it throws error that dependency has not been downloaded.

Comment: Did you just try to running a build, `mvn install`, before going offline? I believe that should fetch the plugins and plugin dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

In order to cache plugins into the .m2/repository folder you would need to specify all plugins explicitly with the `mvn <maven-plugin-name>:help`

You would also need to specify explicit version for each plugin in the `<plugins>` or `<pluginsManagement>` section of your pom.xml

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
      <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
      <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

This is needed to make sure that `mvn install -o` uses the same plugin version.

Ofcourse you would also need to run `mvn dependency:go-offline` to take care of your compile and test dependencies.

`mvn assembly:help compiler:help enforcer:help exec:help failsafe:help install:help jar:help resources:help surefire:help 
mvn dependency:go-offline
mvn compile --offline`

Answer (score 5):

## Maven Go-offline + Isolated Docker Multi-stage Image Builds

My answer is for both a local build or a Dockerized environment, which is isolated on the nature of how docker images are built. This uses Maven `3.6.3-jdk-8`.

With this answer, you know exactly how much time your CI spends on downloading, compiling, testing, packaging...

Finally, also answering to the old question on Jira for the go-offline https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82?focusedCommentId=16997793&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16997793

- Update `pom.xml` dependencies

  - `maven-dependency-plugin`
  - `surefire-junit-platform`
- Call `go-offline` resolving dependencies
- Call any `mvn` command with the switch `--off-line`

## Set latest versions of the plugins

```
@@ -23,6 +23,9 @@
         <junit-jupiter.version>5.5.2</junit-jupiter.version>
         <common-io.version>2.6</common-io.version>
         <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.8.4</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
+        <!-- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82 -->
+        <maven-dependency-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-dependency-plugin.version>
+        <surefire-junit-platform.version>2.22.2</surefire-junit-platform.version>
         <maven-release-plugin.version>2.5.3</maven-release-plugin.version>
         <maven-deploy-plugin.version>2.8.2</maven-deploy-plugin.version>
         <maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-report-plugin.version>
...
...
     <build>
         <plugins>
+            <plugin>
+                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
+                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
+                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
+            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
@@ -135,6 +143,11 @@
                     <target>${java.version}</target>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
+            <plugin>
+                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
+                <artifactId>surefire-junit-platform</artifactId>
+                <version>${surefire-junit-platform.version}</version>
+            </plugin>
```

## Create the Go-offline cache

- This will ensure all the dependencies are downloaded
- More than 3m to download all dependencies

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-8 AS dependencies-downloaded
...
...
COPY pom.xml /usr/src/app/pom.xml
COPY settings.xml /usr/src/app/settings.xml
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f pom.xml -s settings.xml dependency:resolve-plugins dependency:go-offline
```

[image]

## Call compile with --offline

- We can reuse the same image for compilation
- Only takes 7s because nothing is downloaded

```
FROM dependencies-downloaded AS compile
COPY app /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f pom.xml -s settings.xml compile --offline
```

[image]

## Call tests with --offline

- We can reuse the same image for tests
- Taking 18s to run the test cases, without any download whatsoever

```
FROM compile AS tests
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f pom.xml -s settings.xml test --offline
```

[image]

## Call package with --offline

- We can reuse the same image for the final jar
- Skipping even the tests ran in the previous docker image
- Taking way less than before

```
FROM tests AS package
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN mvn -f pom.xml -s settings.xml package -Dmaven.test.skip=true --offline
```

[image]

The final runtime image is a Docker image from the package.

```
FROM JRE
COPY --from package /usr/src/app/target /bin
...
...
```

Answer (score 4):

It should suffice to run a `mvn clean install` on your code. The next time, when you run it in an offline mode you can use the following options:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=..\repository –o clean install
```

`-o` tells Maven **not** to try to update its dependencies over the network and with `-Dmaven.repo.local` you provide the path of the repository which contains all the required dependencies.
Alternatively, you can add the path of the repository in your settings.xml in the `localRepository` tag and add an `<offline>true</offline>`.
You can configure the same in your Maven Eclipse configurations.

Answer (score 1):

After some debugging I found that `maven-dependency-plugin` (version `3.1.1` at the time of writing) is unable to resolve plugin's dependencies when specified like:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>    <--- this is not going to be resolved by dependency:go-offline command !!!
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
   <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

After that I found `go-offline-maven-plugin` which just works! Pls see https://github.com/qaware/go-offline-maven-plugin for more info.

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>de.qaware.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>go-offline-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>x.y.z</version>
</plugin>
```

Current version could be found here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.qaware.maven/go-offline-maven-plugin and Maven issue here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-82

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because Maven hasn't got the metadata available locally to determine if its plugin versions are correct. If you specify exact versions for your plugins (which is a good idea for reproducability anyway), it doesn't need to do the check, so will not try to connect to the remote repositories.

By specify exact versions, I mean that in your project's POM you should add the version to the plugin declaration. For example:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- set the version explicitly-->
    <version>2.0</version>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Note you can also force Maven to use internal repositories instead of Central by setting up repository mirrors. See [this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244654/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-maven-build-independent-of-the-network-connection/1244863#1244863) on using repository managers and mirrors.

In the  config you included, you're setting your remote repository to point to your local repository, this is not a good idea. To run offline you should either pass -o at the command line or add this to your settings.xml:

```
<offline>true</offline>
```

Comment: @Rich, when you mention in specify the version of my plugins you are saying MAVEN plugins right? Which is the best way to do this specification ?? Please see my update in my post to see if I'm doing right. Thanks!