# How do I set up Spring and Maven environment for working offline?

Tags: spring, maven

I need to set up Spring and Maven for working offline. I am working with Spring Tool Suite.What environment variables do I need to configure besides M2 env var? When I try to add dependencies in pom.xml, and type springframework, nothing comes up in the search bar. I get "Core exception Could not calculate build plan Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:m.  I understand STS uses web services to locate the jars, so how do I configure Spring and Maven to work offline?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maven uses central repositoty to update dependencies via internet if you want run it offline you need to configure you local repository.See [Setting local Maven repository](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1364121/Setting-Up-a-Maven-Repository)

Answer (score 0):

This is something that you will find very difficult or near impossible unless you somehow get all the relevant jars from spring and place them in your .m2 repo directory.

Your question has been asked a number of times on here ...

Have a look through these 2 questions which I assume is exactly what you have encountered.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926803/could-the-first-ever-maven-build-be-made-offline)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245076/maven-offline-problem-with-mvn-plugins)

Also one last note ...

After you setup your variables did you restart your PC I know sometimes I forget to do this when updating environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Before you go offline run the following:

mvn dependency:go-offline

That will download all your dependencies and plugins that you need to build your project into ~/.m2/repository.

Once you've run that you can now build your project offline using the '-o' flag:

mvn install -o

It's also possible to configure the offline mode globally by setting the offline property in the ~/.m2/settings.xml file:

true