# I want to use spring tool suite without internet connection

Tags: spring, suite

I can not access internet.

After I've installed spring tool suite, it tries to access internet (I think spring boot) when I open the project popup menu, and then my Eclipse freezes.

Is there any way to use spring suite without internet connection?

Comment: This is a duplicated question, please take a look into this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27710055/how-do-i-set-up-spring-and-maven-environment-for-working-offline

Comment: IMHO it's not a duplicate. SpringBootCore freezes without internet connection, but I do manage to build projects with artifactory/archiva proxies.

Comment: BTW I've solved the pb by declaring a false proxy in eclipse network properties (I've put the IP & port of a local web server). That way the connection fails fast and my "right click menu" pops up.